# How to display TreeTableView with list of T objects as sub items

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have two classes:

```
Project                     Employee                Jobtitle
-------------------------   -------------------     ----------------------
name: String                firstname: String       title: String
employees: List<Employee>   jobtitle: Jobtitle      hourlyWage: BigDecimal
                            birthday: Date
```

**How can I display and edit the values in a treetable like the following?**:

```
Name        fName   Title       Birthday
------------------------------------------  
-Project A
            -Tom    Programmer  09-12-1980
            -Peter  Accountant  03-04-1970
-Project B
-Project D
```

I programmed following so far. How can I add columns for employees because employees is a list?:

```
TreeItem<Project> root
                = new TreeItem<>(new Project("Root", null));

for (Project project : projectData) {
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(project));
}

TreeTableColumn<Project, String> projectCol
    = new TreeTableColumn<>("Projects");
projectCol.setCellValueFactory((cellData) -> cellData.getValue()
                                    .getValue().nameProperty());

//Now how can I add columns for Employee?
//TreeTableColumn<Project, String> projectCol
//  = new TreeTableColumn<>("Firstname");
//projectCol.setCellValueFactory((cellData) -> cellData.getValue()
//                                  .getValue().employeesProperty()...?);

TreeTableView<Project> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>(root);
treeTable.getColumns().add(projectCol);
```

The values come from ObservableLists with values I hard coded (Later I will use JPA to get the data with bidirectional relations i. e. so you can get project from employee and the other way around).

```
private final ObservableList<Jobtitle> jobtitleData
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Jobtitle("Programer", 60),
                    new Jobtitle("Accountant", 70));

private final ObservableList<Person> employeeData
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", jobtitleData.get(0), new Date()),
                new Person("Peter", jobtitleData.get(1), new Date()),);

private final ObservableList<Project> projectData
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Project("Projekt A", employeeData),
                new Project("Projekt B", employeeData));
```

I've read a [tutorial by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm), but they just cover basic types.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @talex I marked the question bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `TreeTableView<T>`, `T` is the type of the item represented **by each row** of the tree table.

The problem with your set-up is that you've declared a `TreeTableView<Project>`, but not every row represents a `Project`: some rows represent `Project`s and some rows represent `Employee`s.

There's no particularly elegant solution to this that I can see. You could simply declare a `TreeTableView<Object>` and then do some type checking (and downcasting) on `cellData.getValue()` in the cell value factories to determine how to create the appropriate value for the cell (e.g. `((Employee)value).firstnameProperty())`if the value is an `Employee` and `new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("")` if not). That is pretty unsatisfactory though.

Another option would be to create a `ProjectEmployeeItem` class specifically for use in the `TreeTableView`. You could do something like

```
public class ProjectEmployeeItem {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");
    private final StringProperty firstName new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstname", "");
    private final ObjectProperty<JobTitle> title new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "title", null);
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "birthday", null);

    // property, get, and set methods ...

    public ProjectEmployeeItem() {
    }

    public ProjectEmployeeItem(Project project) {
        name.bindBidirectional(project.nameProperty());
    }

    public ProjectEmployeeItem(Employee employee) {
        firstname.bindBidirectional(employee.firstnameProperty());
        title.bindBidirectional(employee.titleProperty());
        birthday.bindBidirectional(employee.birthdayProperty());
    }
}
```

Then you create a `TreeTableView<ProjectEmployeeItem>` and do something like

```
TreeItem<ProjectEmployeeItem> root = new TreeItem<>(new ProjectEmployeeItem());
for (Project project : projectData) {
    TreeItem<ProjectEmployeeItem> projectTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(new ProjectEmployeeItem(project));
    for (Employee employee : project.getEmployees()) {
        TreeItem<ProjectEmployeeItem> employeeTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(new ProjectEmployeeItem(employee));
        projectTreeItem.getChildren().add(employeeTreeItem);
    }
    root.getChildren().add(projectTreeItem);
}
```

There are possibly better solutions that involve subclassing `TreeItem` but it would take me considerably more time than I have to see if that approach would work better (or at all..).